# A centralized system to make components communicate to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've been reading StackOverflow for many years now but I finally have a problem I need help with that I cannot find a proper answer to.

Current situation:
I have a library of custom JS components (like a grid, datepicker, popup, etc)
In order for the components to communicate to each other, I have implemented a pub/sub mechanism based on the following two rules:
publisher: event -> message
subscriber: message -> event

in addition to that, I use quite a few custom events, set up using jQuery, and there is a way (using data attributes) to define for each component which event should be triggered on load.

for example:
the grid triggers the 'initialize' event on load, 'initialize' triggers 'refresh', etc.

now, I can have a datepicker that also triggers 'initialize' on load
the problem arises when the datepicker publishes a message that the 'refresh' event of the grid is subscribed to.
what happens then is:

- datepicker **'initialize'** is triggered on load
- while initializing the value is changed, that triggers a **'change'** event
- the **'change'** event publishes a message, let's say **'date_changed'**
- the grid listens to the message and triggers the **'refresh'** event

and that is how the **'refresh'** event of the grid gets triggered before the **'initialize'** event, which is obviously an issue

I am thinking about implementing some sort of event queue, where instead of triggering an event, it is added to a queue and then processed later, but since JavaScript is fundamentally single threaded, it is a bit annoying to implement

Question:
Any ideas how to fix this? including the above, or any other possible solution

thanks a lot for your time

Comment: a flag in each component that it can't `refresh` before it has been initialized? As example some jQueryUI widgets will throw such an error if you try to pass a method to them prior to them having initialized on an element

Comment: Use asynchronous events…

Comment: @Bergi - I'm not sure what you are referring to. Could you give an example or a link?

Comment: @charlietfl - yeah, that is a quick solution, implemented it and seems to work fine. I had to add to the refresh event: if not initialized then initialize first then if the grid does auto refresh just stop. to account for all possibilities. If I don't find a more elegant solution then it's probably going to stay like that

Comment: @Bergi - do you mean like Backbone implements them?

Comment: @AlexPopescu: I don't think so, you'd probably have to help yourself with `setTimeout`. But if you trigger the `change` async, then the grid will get its `initialized` event before the `date_changed` and `refresh` events happen.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a jquery deferred object for internal synchronization within each of your controls where needed? I can't give you a specific example because I don't know how your code is structured.  For example, you have a jquery deferred object that represents the "initialized" state of the Grid component: call it "gridInitialzed".  Ideally this is encapsulated within the Grid component.  You need to make sure that this object is created before the date_changed handler (or anything else that needs it) can get called.  When the Grid triggers it's "initialize" event, it calls "gridInitialized.resolve()".

```
The grid's handler for the "date_changed" event contains:

    gridInitialized.done(function() {
       *code that eventually fires the grid "refresh" event*
    });
```

The function passed to .done is called immediately if gridInitialized is in the resolved state.  If not, execution is delayed until .resolve is called.  The handler returns immediately in either case.

Comment: Interesting idea... I'll think about how that could be applied to my case. Basically each control is just some HTML + delegated events. For example the grid is one table with class="grid". Then all events are delegated to the document.body so that they work if grids are added later.